# Tabulation \t in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.8

I get a string from a MySQL field that contains an horizontal tabulation (\t) like this :

> Lorem ipsum \t dolor sit amet

and I display it with Twig (1.4) like this :

```
<span>{{ item.content | nl2br }}</span>
```

I use nl2br filter because  can have backspace in the text.
It works great for backspaces but not for tabulations ... It still displays like that :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Does anybody have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: HTML will display any space-character, including tabs, as a single whitespace, unless wrapped in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot man !